# C built-in or inline-asm for lock OR

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, atomic

Is there any built-in for this operation (in C) ?

```
lock or QWORD [...], ...
```

In fact, I'm searching for `lock or` in C.

If there isn't any built-in, how can I write it in C inline-asm ?

I'm using GCC (C version 11).

Comment: Depends on the version and extensions of the C language you are using?

Comment: Seems like the standard version looks like [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_fetch_or) (using stdatomic.h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard C11 way of doing this is with <stdatomic.h> and `atomic_fetch_or`.  You can do things like:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

atomic_int  var;

int res = atomic_fetch_or(&var, 0x100);
```

Comment: So the built-in function is `__atomic_fetch_or` because I'm searching for its built-in version